# CSS Transition Delay When Fading-In, but No Delay when Fading Out

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am following a tutorial on how to create CSS tooltips.  Everything works just fine, but there is one modification that I would like to make.  I want the tool tip to show up 3 seconds after I hover over an item, but to fade out immediately when I stop hovering over the item.  This is the (relevant) code I have right now:

```
.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  opacity: 0.7;
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip-text {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transition-delay: 3s;
  visibility: hidden;
  ...
}
```

This ALMOSTS works. It delays showing the tooltip for 3 seconds, like I want.  However, it also delays removing the tooltip (which I do NOT want).  How can I modify my code so that the tool tip fades in 3 seconds after I hover with my mouse and starts fading out immediately when I stop hovering?

Answer (score 2):

Define `transition` properties in `:hover` class. Like this:

```
.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  opacity: 0.7;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transition-delay: 3s;
}

.tooltip-text {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

---

See working demo below. (Try hovering the red box)

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.box:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="tooltip">
    This is tooltip.
  </div>
</div>
```